# Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action on pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages()

Tags: itext7, html2pdf

I got this error on handling a PDF document on itext7 (v7.2.5) and html2pdf (v4.0.5)

com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.

Below you'll find:

**1. the method witch trigger the process**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/split")
public String splitHtml2Pdf() {

    try {
        String inputHtml = "<html><body><landscape>Content 1</landscape><landscape>Content 2</landscape></body></html>";
        Map<Integer, PdfDocument> documentMap = splitHtmlToPdf.splitAndCreateDocuments(inputHtml);

        String outputPdfPath = "/Downloads/output.pdf";
        splitHtmlToPdf.createFinalPdf(documentMap, outputPdfPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return "DONE SPLIT HTML2PDF!";
}
```

**2. the two methods triggered**

```
public Map<Integer, PdfDocument> splitAndCreateDocuments(String inputHtml) throws IOException {

    var converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();

    Map<Integer, PdfDocument> documentMap = new HashMap<>();
    String[] segments = inputHtml.split("<landscape>");

    for (int i = 1; i < segments.length; i++) {
        String segmentHtml = segments[i];
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("temp_" + i + ".pdf"));

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(segmentHtml, pdfDocument, converterProperties);

        documentMap.put(i, pdfDocument);
    }

    return documentMap;
}


public void createFinalPdf(Map<Integer, PdfDocument> documentMap, String outputPath) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument finalPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputPath));
    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(finalPdf);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, PdfDocument> entry : documentMap.entrySet()) {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = entry.getValue();
        // HERE THE METHOD IS THROWN
        int docNrPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();
        merger.merge(pdfDocument, 1, docNrPages);
        pdfDocument.close();
    }

    finalPdf.close();

}
```

**3. THE ERROR IS THOWRON BY the call**

```
int docNrPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();
```

**4. and the call witch close the document is**

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(segmentHtml, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
```

**QUESTION:**

**Any idea how can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent immediate closing of the PdfDocument instance by calling another Method provided by [HtmlConverter](https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfHTML/java/4.0.5/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/HtmlConverter.html): One of the [HtmlConverter#convertToDocument](https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfHTML/java/4.0.5/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/HtmlConverter.html#convertToDocument-java.io.InputStream-com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument-com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties-) overloads for example will return a Document object that isn't closed. You can provide a PdfDocument object or PdfWriter as parameter for example.

In case you don't provide a PdfDocument object as parameter to one of the convertToDocument methods, you can still retrieve it by calling [Document#getPdfDocument](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/7.2.5/com/itextpdf/layout/Document.html#getPdfDocument())

A code example:

```
    public byte[] convertPdf(String inFile) throws IOException {
    var baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
    var doc = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new FileInputStream(inFile),pdf,new ConverterProperties());
    System.out.println(pdf.getNumberOfPages());
    doc.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Your solution save my day. I wish I give you 3 votes :).  One single note, for someone wondering if is possible to pass the HTML string instead the answer is YES, you can pass HTML string as well. Obviously, you should substitute new FileInputStream(inFile) with a String for instance the htmlString.

Comment: Ah, now I see pdf.getNumberOfPages() is returning 0 (zero) that because the doc wasn't closed yet :((((